# Magento: Related products on order success

Tags: php, magento, magento-layout-xml

**Desired result:**

On the order success page I want to show products that are related to the ones purchased by the user.

**What I did so far:**

- product attribute that contains related products
- added `echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products_list');` in `checkout/success.phtml`
- block that extends the product_list, and sets the appropriate collection (*note: this is not a rewrite*)

---

```
class Namespace_CustomersBought_Block_Product_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List {
    protected function _construct() {
        $orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
        // some more code to get the products I need in $relatedProducts
        $this->setCollection($relatedProducts);
    }
}
```

- added in my `custom.xml` the following (paths are correct):

  ```
  <checkout_onepage_success>
      <reference name="content">
          <block type="namespace_customersbought/product_list" name="related_products_list"
                 template="module/product/related_list.phtml" after="-">
          </block>
      </reference>
  </checkout_onepage_success>
  ```

**Where it stopped working**

It renders the div I added in `checkout/success.phtml`, but the `getChildHtml()` call is empty.

Also, I use `Magneto Debug` - and the layout update contains my XML.

**What I need help with**

I would like to understand why this is not working. If I replace `<checkout_onepage_success>` with `<cms_index_index>` I get the desired block on the homepage (without having `getChildHtml()`), so why do they have different behavior?

Also - ideally I wouldn't need to modify the `checkout/success.phtml` file, it should be output automatically.

I know I'm missing something very simple, but I can't figure out what.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you should use "checkout.success" as name of the reference instead of "content".

Comment: getChildHtml() works when you are calling a block, which is nested in your current block call.

Comment: see this thread http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/72520/

Comment: @KalpeshMehta: that was what I was missing, and my train of thought got so close to that idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, there is a problem with the line

```
<reference name="content">
```

This sets your block a child to the content block. You, however have added the output to the `checkout/success.phtml` template, which belongs to the block `checkout.success`. I suggest you replace the xml update with the following

```
<checkout_onepage_success>
    <reference name="checkout.success">
        <block type="namespace_customersbought/product_list" name="related_products_list"
               template="module/product/related_list.phtml" after="-">
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

Comment: Is it possible to show the cross sell in the order success page??